# How to set the "RecordSet", using SQL, to connect to a database

Tags: java, sql, database, recordset

I've been using a tutorial to learn how to create and connect to a database using Java. [Link to the tutorial.](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/connecting_to_a_database_table.html)

In the tutorial it says I need to set the "RecordSet" type to TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE (or whatever type you want to use.)

When I try to call the RecordSet class, I get an error saying:

> cannot find symbol. symbol: variable RecordSet. location: class DataBase

I've tried fixing imports (does nothing), and I've also tried importing the entire SQL package. I think the RecordSet class may have been changed, or it is not in SQL.

Here's my code:

```
package database;

import java.sql.*;

public class DataBase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{
        String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employees";
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM Workers";
        String uName = "nbur4556";
        String uPass = "95086733";

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement(RecordSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
    }catch(SQLException err){
        System.out.println(err.getMessage());
    }

}//End Method


}//End Class
```

So my question is, does anyone know how to set the "RecordSet" class so I can continue setting up the database?

Comment: Its ResultSet not RecordSet

Comment: @Abi make that the answer... Easy rep :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ResultSet and not RecordSet

Change

```
  Statement stmt = con.createStatement(RecordSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```

TO

```
  Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, 
the tutorial may have something wrong